# How do I return a file to the user?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to return a file to the user.

"GetExcel" appears to work and in debug I can see that "ba" has data.

The method completes BUT nothing appears to be returned to the browser - I am hoping to see the file download dialog.

```
C#

       public FileResult GetExcel()
        {           
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

                ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "LBHERE";

                var ba = pck.GetAsByteArray();
                return File(ba, "text/plain", "testFile.txt");
            }

        }

Javascript

        function clickedTest() {
            alert("Test clicked");
            $.get(myPath + "/Employee/GetExcel", { }, function (data) {
            })

        };
```

Comment: Use `location.href = myPath + "/Employee/GetExcel"` instead or use XHR2 to download the file. The regular `jQuery.get` method is not suited for file downloads.

Comment: If you add as answer I will tick it...

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.get()` function pulls data from a webpage into your client-side scripts through AJAX. This is not what you want to do if you want to download a file. Instead, you should open a new tab set to the URL of the file you wish to download.

Try this:

```
function clickedTest() {
  window.open(myPath + "/Employee/GetExcel", "_blank");
}
```

If your browser still isn't initiating a download, but is instead just displaying a file, you may have to go one step further.

Somewhere in your server-side code, when you have access to the Response object, you should set the Content-Disposition header to attachment and provide a filename for the spreadsheet you are serving. This will inform your browser that the file you are requesting is meant to be downloaded, not displayed.

This can be done as follows:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfile.xls")
```

Of course, replace `myfile.xls` with the proper filename for your spreadsheet.